# Updating pages easily with HTML

Tags: php, html

How can I update multiple pages when editing one page?  For example, I am editing index.html, and I am changing its footer (which all other pages have).  When I change the footer I want the other pages on my domain to be updated as well. Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for server-side code.

Comment: What tool are you using to create your web pages with? And are you using any javascript or server-side code? In what language? Here is one summary article of the different [approaches](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ssi/a/aa052002a.htm)

Comment: put the footer in some other file like `footer.php` & call it back on pages that you want.By doing this your `footer` gets updated with you updating at one single place

Comment: Consider moving to a content-management-system, such as WordPress or Drupal. Many hosting sites offer these for free.

Comment: I am mainly using HTML and PHP.

Comment: why don't you copy paste :) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a major reason why platforms like PHP and ASP.NET exist; they can help you dynamically generate HTML containing common sections like headers and footers that are defined in one place.  One simple alternative that may be available for you is [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

**Update**:

Since you said you're using PHP, rather than having pages with the `.html` extension, you should write your pages in PHP.  That way, you can include separate files containing your headers and footers in each page, so any changes to those only have to be done in one place, i.e.:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<!-- Your page-specific content -->

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.  You can use an editor that opens files of a certain project, and use regular expressions to edit.

Or a more common way to achieve this is to use SSI's or Server Side Includes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).  This is more common, and less likely to destroy pages if a regular expression isn't formed properly.

If you're using a different engine (like PHP) you can do something like file includes (require_once, include, etc), to pull the information from a single place.  This is similar to SSI's in concept, except it requires another engine to parse the page.

Modern day IDEs for Web Design (DreamWeaver) include this type of functionality within them too.  You only need to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

For such automatic updating you can create a function in PHP

```
function generate_footer() {
echo "<p>Page maintained by Lucifer</p>";
}
```

and in the HTML code you just have to write this

```
<div class= "footer">
<?php generate_footer()?>
</div>
```

this is in php you can use any other server scripting language you wish